# System can not find the specified path while starting a windows service

Tags: java, windows

I have registered a windows service but when trying to start it says,

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 2:

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I checked the regedit where iamgepath is not getting set properly.
path should be D:\abc\Windows.exe but it is D:abcWindows.exe

I am using java to do above things.

Please help.....

Answer (score 0):

Replace **slash** `\` with **double slash** `\\` like below:

```
"D:\\abc\\Windows.exe"
```

and it should work

Answer (score 0):

In Java '\' is a character which define escape sequences like \n means new line character, So if you want to use \ as a character in your input string place one more \ before your .

So if you want to write a\b\c write a\b\c

System.out.println("a\b\c"); will print a\b\c